# jQuery widget bridge on a non-function based object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

As part of upgrading from jQuery 1.6.4 to 1.9.x, I'm trying to understand how to use jQuery widget bridge to allow access to functions for widgets created as a standalone object, rather than as an extension to jQuery.

All of the examples ([like this one](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-jquery-ui-widget-factory-bridge/)) use a prototype function as the source definition of the object, which doesn't seem to map for defining an object directly from a {} based definition.

For example I am defining a widget like this:

```
var ControlPanel = {

    instance: null,

    options: {
        //Some options here
    },

    simpleFunction: function(){
        alert("I am a function");
    },

    _init: function() {
        //Some init stuff here
    }
}

$.widget("basereality.controlPanel", ControlPanel); // create the widget

//This doesn't appear to work...
$.widget.bridge('controlPanel', $.basereality.controlPanel); //'Bridge' the widget
```

And then creating an instance of it by doing:

```
var controlPanelParams = {
  // some options go here
};

var newControlPanel = $('#controlPanel').controlPanel(controlPanelParams);
```

I would now like to be able to call the method 'simpleFunction' on the created object, which I've tried to do by doing:

```
newControlPanel.simpleFunction();
//and 
$(newControlPanel).simpleFunction();
```

Both of which give a 'Object does not have a method called simpleFunction' error.

So what am I doing wrong and how are you meant to use $.widget.bridge on non-function based objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. Instead of this:

```
$(newControlPanel).addControl(smartyControlPanel);
```

Access the function by calling it as a parameter like this:

```
newControlPanel.controlPanel("addControl", smartyControlPanel);
```

And I also converted my code to have be based of a function for the first prototype:

```
var ControlPanel = function(options, element){
    this.options = options;
    this.element = element;

    this._init();
};

ControlPanel.prototype = {
    //Everything else in here
}
```

Though having to call it as a parameter is a lot less easy to understand than it was calling it directly as a function.